# How to get specific parts of a string from an array where every string has a different length?

Tags: arrays, string, substr

I have an array of strings, they contain information about objects position in 3D space.The positions are separated with commas. The first one before the comma is x position, second one is y and third one is z. Some of these strings are:

`string a = "0.95,2.34,0"`  `string b = "18.05,5,0"` `string c ="112.1,10,3"` 
I want to assign 0.95 into float xPos, 2.34 into yPos, 0 into zPos etc.

I want to do these one by one in a for loop for every string in the array.

I couldn't use substr because they have different lengths. 
How can i get the substrings between the commas and put them into variables?

-I use c++

P.S sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is a `Split()` type of method in most languages. You would call the method on the incoming string, and split it on the comma then you would have a resulting array with two strings, one of each value. Place the first value in X and the second in Y. You might want a helper method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the x,y and z string values using RegularExpressions. Then you could use a TryParse method to cast the value to double.